# Mvc - Download multiple files as Zip Error as "Unreadable content" while opening downloaded zipped file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using an ASP.NET MVC application and I want to download multiple files as zipped. I have written code with memory stream and `ZipArchive` in my controller action method. With that code, I am able to successfully download the files as zipped folder. But when I unzipped those and trying to open them then I am getting the error as below.

1. Opening Word document with Microsoft Word - Word found unreadable content error
2. Opening image file (`.png`) - doesn't support file format error

Here is my controller method code to zip the files

```
if (sendApplicationFiles != null && sendApplicationFiles.Any())
{                    
    using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Create an archive and store the stream in memory.
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (var file in sendApplicationFiles)
            {
                // Create a zip entry for each attachment
                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(file.FileName);

                // Get the stream of the attachment                              
                using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(file.FileData))
                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                {
                    // Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                }
            }
        }

        return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the document content should load without error

Answer (score 0):

I did not investigate your code, but this link might help. There are few examples.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files